# Loop that will get integers from user and output sum and average

Tags: java, loops

I have to write a program the gets a sequence of numbers in a loop that will go for a maximum of 10 times. but stop if the user enters a negative number, and then display the sum, and average. I'm having trouble getting my program to stop after the user inputs 10 numbers. and also the sum and average don't output the right answer. any help on fixing this would be great. here's my code:

```
        while(count<MAX){
            while(num>=02){
                count++;
                sum=sum+num;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter a number, negative to STOP: ");
            num=input.nextInt();
        }
        avg=sum/count;
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println("You entered " + count + " positive numbers.");
        System.out.println("The sum = " + sum );
        System.out.println("The average = " + avg );
    }
}
```

Comment: we are not here to participate in a programming contest with Level 1.
What is your question ?

Comment: it's not good form to post your exercises as SO questions. If you have a question, please describe only the problem you have, not the entire exercise you're trying to do. Copy-paste is easy, but does not take into consideration that you're asking other people for help, not robots. Show us you're willing to take the effort to specifically describe your problem, for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the following for your while loop.

```
sum= num; 
while(count<MAX-1){
  System.out.println("Enter a number, negative to STOP: ");
  num=input.nextInt();
  if (num < 0){
      break; //or whatever else you want to do in this case
  }
  sum= sum + num;
  count++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, your previous code had an infinite loop because you never game the computer a chance to redefine its condition.